# Route with ID in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to generate a settings page for my Ember-Cli app. The URL I would like is `/settings/:id/` with separate routes such as `/settings/:id/overview` and `/settings/:id/password`.

> How do I create nested routes using Ember CLI? I've found plenty of examples for Ember, but not for CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: As of v0.1.5, Ember-CLI has fixed the issue with not generating the routing map correctly. Running the commands below should now generate the correct code in `router.js`. It also added a `path` option for nested routes (rather than resources). You can see the changelog [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#section). It looks as if the changelog notes are currently the only documentation of that feature, but they're easy enough to understand.

---

Right now, there is no way to fully generate nested routes or resources with Ember-CLI (as far as I can tell). You can have it generate the files for you, but you'll have to edit `router.js` yourself. For instance, if I run the following lines:

```
ember generate resource settings
ember generate route settings/overview
```

You'll get the following `router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('settings', { path: 'settings/:settings_id' }, function() { });
    this.route('settings/overview');
});
```

This is probably just a limitation in the way Blueprints currently works. Go ahead and generate your routes as you see above, then just modify `router.js` by hand to nest the route calls instead of making them top-level:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('settings', { path: 'settings/:settings_id' }, function() {
        this.route('overview');
    });
});
```

Also, if you want to create a nested route, not a nested resource, I'm not sure there is a blueprint for that yet. I would just generate a resource and then change it to a route manually.

Comment: That is creating the routes manually, he is asking how to `generate` them using `ember-cli`

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have missed the word `generate`. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: @Sam I updated the answer with a link. It looks like this is now possible as of v0.1.5 of Ember-CLI.